# srss scheduled exporting into excel file

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am developing a ssrs project which takes data from oracle table. The question is to export data from the oracle table into excel file into a certain folder every morning at 6 o'clock, the implementation supposed to be added into the ssrs project. is it possible without any additional projects?

Comment: Does the report work now? Setup a subscription for it.

Comment: Yes, report just gets data from oracle table and shows it on web page. on the web page the report can be exported to excel file manually.

Comment: Correct, but if it's a report on the SSRS portal, you can setup a subscription to export the excel file to a shared folder at a scheduled time.